# Breaking line JSX react

Tags: reactjs, jsx

What should I do to break line when the property message is rendered inside a `<p>` in a different component? I can not get my head around this one... I tried with `<br>` or with `\n`   but it keeps be rendered in one line...

```
const modalOn = (date, clinic) => {
  setError({
    title: "Do you want to remove the following shift?",
    message: "DATE: " + date + " CLINIC: " + clinic,
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to insert `\n` in your message and then when you have to render it you put something like

```
{message.split("\n").map((item, index) => {
return index === 0 ? item : [<br key={index} />, item];
})}
```

I don't know if it's the right way to do such a thing but it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

you need to use pre tag :

```
    const ReportMap = () => {
    useEffect(()=>{

    },[])
   const t= {
        title:`Do you want to remove the following shift?`,
            message: "DATE: " + "date" + " CLINIC: " + "clinic",
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <pre>{`${t.title}\n${t.message}`}</pre>
           
        </div>
    );
};

export default ReportMap;
```

or give white-space to p tag :

```
const ReportMap = () => {

   const t= {
        title:`Do you want to remove the following shift?`,
            message: "DATE: " + "date" + " CLINIC: " + "clinic",
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <p style={{whiteSpace: "pre"}}>{`${t.title}\n${t.message}`}</p>
        </div>
    );
};

export default ReportMap;
```

they worked for me very well.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys... I think I did not make a very clear question. I wanted to break after the question mark, then after the date.

I found a solution which seems to work well.

```js
  const modalOn = (date, clinic) => {
    setError({
      title: "Do you want to remove the following shift?",
      message: ["DATE: ", fullDate, <br />," CLINIC: ", clinic]
    });
  };
```